# How to save obtained model in terms of SSDMetaArch object into .pbtxt or .ckpt

Tags: tensorflow, model, object-detection

using .config and .proto files and with the help of model_builder.py (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/lstm_object_detection/model_builder.py) I have successfully got a model which SSDMetaArch (/LSTMSSDMetaArch) object. Can anyone please tell me how to save this obtained model from model_builder.py to .pbtxt? or is there any other steps required in between obtained final model as SSDMetaArch Object and getting the model inside .pbtxt?